# How to receive correct file and directory paths from user?

Tags: python

I want to receive import and export path from user. From [this documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html) I've known I can give the string property a sub-type which turns it to a file or directory selector, the problem is that they give a wrong path, some parts are replaced by ".." and some parts are not typed at all.

I want to receive those paths from user to use them later when the user executes an operator (by clicking a button when everything is ready).

[image]

this is my code:

```
class myPaths(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    @classmethod
    def register(cls):
        bpy.types.Scene.myPaths = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=myPaths)

    @classmethod
    def unregister(cls):
        del bpy.types.Scene.myPaths

    fileExportPath: StringProperty(
        name="export path",
        subtype="DIR_PATH",
        description="some description"
    )
    jsonImportPath: StringProperty(
        name="import path",
        subtype="FILE_PATH",
        description="path of .json file to import."
    )
    fileName:StringProperty(
        name="output file name",
        description="Write file name without any file extension."
    )
```

How can I receive correct file and directory paths form user?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution [here](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.path.html). use `bpy.path.abspath(path)` to get the absolute path to the file or directory.